# Whitelist akamai IPs at azure application gateway

Tags: azure, ip, whitelist, akamai

Is it possible to whitelist multiple IPs of akamai at application gateway using azure portal .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Akamai application you're using, you should look at the [Origin IP ACL](https://techdocs.akamai.com/property-mgr/docs/origin-ip-access-control) recently added to Property Manager. It provides you with a preset list of IPv4 and IPv6 CIDR ranges that you can place in your firewall.